# Oriental character with FreeTDS, MSSQL

Tags: sql-server, linux, freetds, mssql-jdbc

I am with problem to insert an Oriental nvarchar in database using MSSQL and FreeTDS. 
When I inserted it was like this in database: `é­éå»ºè­°æç»æª¢`.

Answer (score 1):

The solution was add the client charset: UTF-8

so it apear in database like '`鄭重建議文獻檢`'.

Comment: Nice dude. I had this problem too. That solved it nice.

Comment: charset of freetds.conf